# maximum volume enclosed in a region

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, optimization

I have a general question that I don't know where I should start; of course, any reference also might help.

Let $A_{n\times k}$ be a matrix of constants, $b\in \mathbb{R}^k$ a vector of constants, and $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  I want to solve the maximization problem

\begin{equation}
\max_{\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^k} \int_{\mathcal{A}} d\mathbb{P}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A})
\end{equation}

where $\mathcal{A} = \{\mathbf{x} : \mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{v} + b^T \mathbf{v}\ge 0\}$.

In other word, there is a set of linear subspaces and I am trying to maximize the measure of the region enclosed by them.